# java8 stream apis throwing incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to Integer[] when converting String array to Integer array

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

My below codes:

```
String[] valStrs=data.split(";");//data is a string
Integer[] vals=Arrays.stream(valStrs).map(Integer::valueOf).toArray();
```

is throwing:

```
error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to Integer[] [in Codec.java]
        Integer[] vals=Arrays.stream(valStrs).map(Integer::valueOf).toArray();
```

I think I am trying to get a `String` stream, then map `String` into `Integer` by `Integer::valueOf`, and collect these `Integer` into an array.

So why this error? Did a quick search and cann't find the answer.

---

UPDATE:

With the fact that  `int[] arr= Arrays.stream(valStrs).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();` works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the constructor reference to the integer array in to the `toArray` like this. Otherwise it will create an `Object[]` by default.

```
Arrays.stream(valStrs).map(Integer::valueOf).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

`mapToInt` creates an `IntStream`, and it's `toArray()` function returns an `int[]`. Here's the declaration.

```
int[] toArray();
```

Conversely, `map(Integer::valueOf)` creates a `Stream<Integer>` and it's `toArray` returns an `Object[]` unless otherwise specified. Here's the implementation.

```
@Override
public final Object[] toArray() {
    return toArray(Object[]::new);
}
```

The invocation of `toArray(Integer[]::new)` will call this overloaded method.

```
public final <A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)
```

Here's an excerpt from the documentation.

> Returns an array containing the elements of this stream, using the
>   provided generator function to allocate the returned array.
>
> generator a function which produces a new array of the desired type
>   and the provided length

Comment: Works.May I ask why `int[] arr= Arrays.stream(valStrs).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();` work?

Comment: @ZhaoGang Because `IntStream`s "toArray()" is typed as `int[] toArray()`. Compare that with `Object[] toArray()` in `Stream`.